# Check ETA approval

Tags: australia, visa-free-entry, eta

I've applied for ETA through EasyETA.com. It says in the confirmation email that my application has been approved. However, I would like to double confirm my approval (as I did not apply through the official Australia immigration department immi.gov.au.

Is there a way for me to check it with the immigration department?

Answer (score 5):

It seems best to go to the official Australia Department of Immigration and Border Protection  [Electronic Travel Authority](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/) web site to [check your ETA](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas?submit=check).

It appears to be legitimate for third party web sites to accept applications for an ETA. It is noted by an [official web site](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Appl/Electronic-travel-authority) that: "Your travel agent or airline can also book your ETA."